# octobercms backend form - Refresh form after fields change?

Tags: octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

with builder plugin, I try to validate my form fields.
I used filterFields() to check fields on the fly.
Now I want to make some date validation before DB save.
I used the following code to clear a field like in filterFields().

```
// Called before the model is validated (bouton SAVE)
public function beforeValidate() {
    if ($this->date_begin > $this->date_end) {
        $this->attributes['date_end'] = null;      // clear date
    }
}
```

my problem is that **I would like to refresh the form field or the complete form** to reflect the modifications.
Would somebody put me on the way to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: No one could help me for the REFRESH ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller:

```
public function formAfterSave($model)
{ 
   return $this->formRenderFieldResult['#Form-field-Controller-date_end-group'] = $this->formRenderField('date_end', ['useContainer' => false]);
}
```

Where '#Form-field-Controller-date_end-group' is the field group name in your form, inspect element.

Comment: Thanks James, but after many tries, I'm not sure to understand.
I get a popup error "Form behavior does not contain a field for 'date_end'."

Comment: Change 'date_end' base on the field that you use in the yaml.